# Uploading files **from** Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file (stored in blobstore and accessed with BlobReader) from my App Engine application to another website.

I have tried urllib2_file as well as MultipartPostHandler and requests, but they do not work due to GAE module restrictions.

File is sent in a POST request, I'm am aware of the 1MB limit of requests, it's not a concern as the files are below 1MB in size.

Comment: how large is the file? are you doing this via a POST request?

Comment: You're probably hitting the 1MB urlfetch limit. Would it be possible to post a blobstore URL to the other website, and have that site pull the data from that URL?

Comment: POST request, and the limitation on request size is not going to be a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question as I believe this is a better solution: [use the requests library](http://python-requests.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to build your own multipart form data using the `encode_multipart_formdata` method from here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/

And use that as the body of your urlfetch POST.